# GUI Development on Unix and Windows Server

Tags: c++, windows, linux, visual-studio, user-interface

What tool (language) should I choose to Develop a GUI if I am familiar with c/c++ and concepts of oops such that it enhances my c/c++ skills more rather than learning a new language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like [WxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) a lot. It works well on Linux, Windows and Macs. I've used it for several small applications. Also, if you don't care about native look and feel, you may like [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/) too. I've had good results with both of those in C++.

Comment: Visual designers are important when doing GUI development also.

Answer (score 2):

QT and C# would work since you already know c/c++

Comment: Qt is probably much more relevant than C#

Comment: I think C# is the quickest way to develop GUI apps

Comment: Well, Mono has become quite stable. It's just necessary to be careful not to use unimplemented features. I would still agree that Qt would be more sensible, though.

Answer (score 0):

I will use Java and Swing or even JavaFX